# Modal window not in focus by default in cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, focus, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to pop up an alert (NSAlert) message box in my cocoa application. But it doesn't focus on this alert window by default. Instead the focus is still on the mainWindow of the application. Following is my code:-

> [Alert beginSheetModalForWindow:[NSApp mainWindow]
>                         modalDelegate:g_pOpenGLView               didEndSelector:@selector(CNNotifyHardwareDecodeFailDidEnd:ReturnCode:ContextInfo:)
>                           contextInfo:nil];

When I run this message box as [Alert runModal] it works properly and it gives full focus to the alert-box. But I don't want to do it that way because it blocks the main window processing. Can someone help me with this? I'm not able to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What is the distinction you're making to decide whether the alert has "full focus"?

Comment: I want one of the options in alert box to be selected by default. And user shouldn't be able to interact with other windows unless alert box is dismissed. If so, I would say that alert box has full focus.

Comment: The entire point of sheets is that they're only modal for the window they appear on. If you want to block interaction for all windows in your app, then use `-runModal`, which is designed for it.

Comment: Yes you're right. And I want to do the same : "Alert box should be modal for the window that it appears on". But its not being so. The main Window is still taking keyboard inputs even when alert box window is present as modal sheet on top of it.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Well that is pretty unexpected behaviour! Sheets have always worked great for me. Suggest you post a sample project that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
[[Alert window] makeKeyWindow];
```

Comment: Still doesn't get the keyboard focus. Do you suggest anything else?